# FFmpeg corrupted output from concatenation

Tags: video, ffmpeg, editing

EDIT/UPDATE: current solution is to run this code on all files `ffmpeg -i up.mp4 -vf scale=1920:1080 -crf 22 reUP.mp4` so resolution, but also frames per second match.

[image]

I used to be able to open CMD, type `CD C:\Users\...` and then `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i xmylist.txt -crf 22 -c copy x1.mp4`

[image: xmylist]

The recording are from same phone, some from front cam, some from back cam. I understand this could cause non-identical problems? but it worked fine until recently.

Now the output is corrupted with this log: [image]
The individual video files play just fine, so does most of the concatted output, but some sections become like this and freeze: [image]

Comment: @llogan

https://i.ibb.co/zSw7Fky/bilde.png
It used to work just fine combining front and rear :/ I tried updating to no avail.

Comment: @llogan The individual files play well on VLC and Potplayer, but both media players fail to play them when concatenated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating two video files with different resolutions.

- `front.mp4` is 1920x1080
- `rear.mp4` is 1280x720

Reproducing the problem is not too difficult (you may place the code in a `.bat` file):

```batch
rem Create tmplist.txt
echo file 'front.mp4' > tmplist.txt
echo file 'rear.mp4' >> tmplist.txt

rem Create video with resolution 192x108 for example (instead of 1920x1080)
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=25 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=300 -acodec aac -ar 22050 -vcodec libx265 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 3 front.mp4

rem Create video with resolution 128x72 for example (instead of 1280x720)
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=128x72:rate=25 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -acodec aac -ar 22050 -vcodec libx265 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 3 rear.mp4

rem Concatenate:
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i tmplist.txt -c copy tmp.mp4
```

---

Result (after 3 seconds):
[image]

---

Solution: Convert all the concatenated input videos to the same resolution.

Note:

- At lease some for the videos must be re-encoded.

I suppose the best solution is to convert the lower resolution to the higher, and then apply `concat`:

```batch
ffmpeg -y -i rear.mp4 -vf scale=192:108,setsar=1 -vcodec libx265 -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p resized_rear.mp4

ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i tmplist.txt -c copy tmp2.mp4
```

---

**Less recommended solution:**

There is single solution, but it re-encode all the videos (reducing quality).
I don't know if there is a solution using a text file.

Example for concatenating two files - the second video is resized:

```
ffmpeg -y -i front.mp4 -i rear.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=192:108,setsar=1[v1];[0:v][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -vcodec libx265 -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p tmp_resized.mp4
```

Comment: Why was I able to do this without trouble before?
Does it have something to do with me changing filetype back and forth (.mp4 --> .zzz --> .mp4)  Does that corrupt headers or something?

Comment: I don't know... Are you sure you had two video files with different resolutions before? Is it possible that you modified the resolution settings of one of the cameras?